# Context menu in headless viewer in forge viewer

Tags: react-native-ios, autodesk-forge, headless, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to use headless viewer of autodesk for ipad app with react native web view for hiding the bottom toolbar. But using that I could not get the context menu on right click. Is there any way the context menu can be generated in headless forge viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess context menus are also not part of the headless viewer. All you would need to do to turn the normal viewer into headless would be to add a custom css rule:

```
.adsk-viewing-viewer .adsk-toolbar {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: the css worked, thanks!
does the headless viewer affect the rendering speed of the model, if not, is there any way to optimize the model rendering speed?

Comment: rendering should be the same, the only difference with headless viewer is that it comes with no UI and no controls, some extensions will not be loaded. There isn't anything special you can do about rendering as it is already optimized. Turning on progressive rendering can help for large models with lots of components: viewer.setProgressiveRendering(true)

Comment: is there any way to use the above css to toggle the visibility of the bottom toolbar after the model has been rendered?