# Show context menu in Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to show a context menu using Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D (Headless Viewer).

I can get the context menu to show up easily when using Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D as my viewer type but i don't want to use this viewer type as it has a toolbar and i don't want it to appear for this viewer. I can't use the css approach suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49665322/context-menu-in-headless-viewer-in-forge-viewer) as I also want the toolbar in a different viewer in the same application.

My attempt to initialise a context menu using Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D (Headless Viewer) look like the following:

```
var contextMenu = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ObjectContextMenu(viewer);
        viewer.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
        viewer.registerContextMenuCallback('CustomContextMenuItems', function (menu, status) {
            if (status.hasSelected) {
                if(menu === null){menu=[];}
                while (menu.length > 0) {
                    menu.pop();
                }

                menu.push({
                    title: 'Do Something',
                    target: function () {
                        console.log("Doing something")
                    }
                });

            } 
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context menu is intended to be used with `GuiViewer3D`. It's most likely relying on some of its HTML or CSS setup, which is why it's causing issues with `Viewer3D`. If you need this level of customization of the GUI, I'd suggest to implement a separate, simple context menu instead of bending the built-in one.

Comment: Hi Petr,
Any guides or examples for creating a simple context menu?
Cheers

Comment: Hi Neil, I'm sure there are some tutorials for this online, for example: https://www.bypeople.com/html-css-js-context-menu-snippet or https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-a-custom-right-click-menu-to-a-webpage.